# How to test Thymeleaf with MockMVC and standaloneSetup and no WebApplicationContext?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf, mockmvc

I want to test a controller, that returns page using Thymeleaf template, with `MockMVC`.

This is my test:

```
class PostControllerTest {

    ...

    @BeforeClass
    fun setUp() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(postController)
                .build()
    }

    @Test
    fun testGetFirstPost() {
        every { postRepository.find(1) } returns post

        mockMvc.perform(get("/post/1"))
                .andExpect(status().`is`(200))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("post", equalTo(post)))
    }
}
```

But I get the exception:

> Circular view path [post]: would dispatch back to the current handler
>   URL [/post] again.

Name of the controller mapping and the template are the same (`post`).

I don't want to use `WebApplicationContext` or something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `ViewResolver` to recognize template:

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(postController)
            .setViewResolvers(viewResolver())
            .build()
```

Where `viewResolver()` is:

```
private fun viewResolver(): InternalResourceViewResolver {
    val viewResolver = InternalResourceViewResolver()

    // configuration
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/templates/")
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".html")

    return viewResolver
}
```